# Docker compose force recreate

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I use the following command to update my containers

```bash
docker-compose up -d --build --force-recreate
```

I added `--build` to build images before starting containers and added `--force-recreate` to force deleting and recreating containers

It doesn't work as I expect. Sometimes containers use old images, I have to manually delete containers and images and `docker-compose up -d --build` to fix the problem

How can I have a single docker command to update my containers

Answer (score 1):

Try this

OLD ANSWER:

`docker-compose up -d --build --no-cache --force-recreate`

EDIT:

I combined two commands `compose build` and `compose up -d --build` by mistake above, it does not work like that, the answer is:

`docker-compose build --no-cache && docker-compose up -d --force-recreate`

Comment: unknown flag: --no-cache

Comment: Whops, I mixed up docker-compose build with docker-compose up -d --build:
this is the way it should work. 


```docker-compose build --no-cache && docker-compose up -d --force-recreate```

Comment: Thanks. the `--no-cashe` caused to not using cache when building the image. But I want to use caches to make build process faster. I just want to know why `--force-recreate` doesn't work